# Build Failure on Android Studio"\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e5ae7cf0f80ee425fe42a4574342c71c\aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-windows"

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to use

`dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    }`

But it brings the error while building my project. Every time I change the classpath to 3.2.0 the application seems to build fine but with warnings.

I have tried cleaning the project to no avail.

What's the best way to use classpath "3.5.3" and still avoid the errors/warnings from 'aapt2-3.5.3-5435860-windows' when building the project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First try Invalidate & restart Option in File menu to invalidate all cached build files

if your error still persist then try clearing cache folder with specific gradle version in your User folder in C drive for example for me the path to the folder is as follows

```
C:\Users\myUser\.gradle\caches
```

and

```
C:\Users\myUser\.AndroidStudio3.5\system\caches
```

these folders might be hidden

Comment: Thank you so much. The Invalidate and Restart option worked perfectly.

Comment: On Linux, you can empty the gradle cache using `rm -Rf ~/.gradle/cache`. (You might need to run the "Invalidate Caches / Restart" option in addition.)